# Interpretation of Intercept in mixed model with repeated contrasts

Tags: lme4-nlme, contrasts, intercept

I am running the following logistic mixed model in lme4:

```r
AllCond_logme <- glmer(Response ~ Condition + (Condition | Pt_ID), 
                       family = binomial(), data = lme.df,
                       control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

where Response is a binary outcome (1 vs 0).

I computed repeated contrasts and applied them to the Condition predictor, which is a factor with 4 levels (0, 25%, 50%, 75%). The contrasts are:

1. cH01: 25% - 0
2. cH02: 50% - 25%
3. cH03: 75% - 50%

To create the contrasts, I first computed the following hypothesis matrix:

|  | 0 | 25% | 50% | 75% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Intercept | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25 | 0.25 |
| cH01 | -1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| cH02 | 0 | -1 | 1 | 0 |
| cH03 | 0 | 0 | -1 | 1 |

where the intercept is the mean probability of Response=1 across all conditions.

I then use `ginv()` to convert to a contrast matrix and apply this to 'Condition'.

*Note: I now realise that this was equivalent to using the contr.sdif() function in the MASS package.

The mixed model results are as follows:

```
Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -0.1197     0.1021  -1.173    0.241    
ConditioncH01   1.6971     0.1587  10.692   <2e-16 ***
ConditioncH02   1.9622     0.1108  17.713   <2e-16 ***
ConditioncH03   1.5400     0.1370  11.240   <2e-16 ***
```

The results seem plausible except for my result for the intercept.

I believe that the intercept should represent the mean probability of Response=1 across all conditions, and the mixed model tests whether this is significantly different to 0. The probability of Response=1 should be significantly different to 0 (across all conditions, about 40% of responses are Response=1). Is my interpretation of the intercept correct, and why is it not significant?

I've also attached a plot of Response= 1 ('Tone Present' response) across the conditions as a visual aid to understand the analysis and also to demonstrate how the intercept should differ from 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an attempt at answering my own question...

I believe that the intercept here is indeed the mean (log likelihood) of Response=1 across all conditions. The *p*-value for the intercept tests whether this significantly differs from 0. While the mean probability of Response=1 across conditions is ~48%, the standard deviation for this value is ~35%. I think this large standard deviation may be the cause of the non-significant intercept in this case.